# Correct specification of a hierarchial model for analysing temporal trends

Tags: multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

My data has a nested structure, which is suitable for hierarchical modelling. The categorical variable used as a hierarchical level is **county**. As the counties are unequally sized (different number of subjects), I use hierarchical modelling for analysing temporal changes.

**First, am I correct, that the hierarchical modelling allows reporting temporal changes in a way, where all counties (small and big-sized) have equal contribution to the conditional effects?** Or in other words, the results are less affected by the big counties.

**Second, which of the following model structures should I use if I am interested in county-level trends only (not country-wide trends):**

**A**

```
y ~ time + (time | county)
```

**B**

```
y ~ (time | county)
```

When plotting the conditional effects of these models, the results are more or less the same. I use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html

Comment: What do you mean by county-level and county-wide trends ? Do you mean within and between counties ?

Comment: Thanks! County-level: I plot trends for each county. CountRy level: i am not interested in showing countRy-wide trends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two models:

```
y ~ time + (time | county)
```

and

```
y ~ (time | county)
```

..only differ in the presence of the fixed effect for `time`. In the first model, the software will estimate a fixed (overall) effect for time, and each `county` will have it's own offset from this fixed effects.

In the 2nd model, since the fixed effect of `time` is absent, the overall effect of time is implicitly zero. Each `county` has it's own effect for `time`, but rather than being an offset from the fixed effect, it is an offset from zero.

In most cases, it rarely makes sense to exclude the fixed effect unless you know that the overal trend is zero.

Comment: Super answer! Could you please comment the first point also about hierarchical models.